# Coloring a random graph in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, random

I have a script that implements greedy coloring in python, in other words it colors a graph with four colors. I wanted to generate a random graph and then pass it into the script found on the link above to color it.
This is how I generate a random graph (in the shape of a dictionary):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = {i: sample([j for j in q if i != j], randrange(1, len(q) - 1))
for i in q}
```

So what i need now is some kind of function that passes the created dictionary into the greedy coloring script, because if i enter the graph d in the function in the script called *greedycoloring* I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9244016A-6D10-4627-B39B-6D63D3F9D22C/Pythonista3/Documents/nuovaprova.py", line 88, in <module>
    greedyColoring(d, 5)
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9244016A-6D10-4627-B39B-6D63D3F9D22C/Pythonista3/Documents/nuovaprova.py", line 33, in greedyColoring
    if (result[i] != -1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You should be able to use `greedycoloring(d,5)`.

Comment: I get the error “list index out of range”

Comment: Could you [edit] and paste the full error message into your question?

Comment: I added the error I get when doing ‘greedycoloring(d,5)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `list` q from 0 as shown below:

```
q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {i: sample([j for j in q if i != j], randrange(1, len(q) - 1))
     for i in q}
```

Then, you can directly pass dictionary `d` into the script as :

```
 greedyColoring(d, 5)
```

The given script represents graph as `list of lists` where index of list represents the node and its corresponding value represents its adjacent nodes, so you can also convert `d`  into list of list as `[node for node in d.values()]` and then pass into the function as:

```
greedyColoring([node for node in d.values()], 5)
```